# Вытягивание текста из другой программы

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

Установлен СофтФон MicroSip, и при поступлении входящего звонка необходимо вытаскивать номер телефона.
Чем в этом случае пользоваться?

Answer (score 6):

Для доступа к UI элементам программ есть 2 технологии доступа [UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) и [MSAA](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-and-microsoft-active-accessibility)

Для первого есть неплохая обертка [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Cruciatus) которая позволяет работать с WinForms и WPF через Selenum WebDriver.
Смотреть какие элементы с какими атрибутами есть на форме можно через утилиты Inspect или UISpy взять можно [здесь](https://github.com/blackrosezy/gui-inspect-tool)

Пример работы с WinForm используя Winium (взято из Readme)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    using System.Windows.Automation;
    using Winium.Cruciatus.Core;
    using Winium.Cruciatus.Extensions;

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var calc = new Winium.Cruciatus.Application("C:/windows/system32/calc.exe");
            calc.Start();

            var winFinder = By.Name("Calculator").AndType(ControlType.Window);
            var win = Winium.Cruciatus.CruciatusFactory.Root.FindElement(winFinder);
            var menu = win.FindElementByUid("MenuBar").ToMenu();

            menu.SelectItem("View$Scientific");
            menu.SelectItem("View$History");

            win.FindElementByUid("132").Click(); // 2
            win.FindElementByUid("93").Click(); // +
            win.FindElementByUid("134").Click(); // 4
            win.FindElementByUid("97").Click(); // ^
            win.FindElementByUid("138").Click(); // 8
            win.FindElementByUid("121").Click(); // =

            calc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не по теме основного вопроса, скажите таким способом можно кликать кнопками в вебвью? Многие современные приложения представляют из себя родное для ОС окно-обертку, внутри которого запущен вебвью (примеры - слак, скайп для линукса и т.п.)

Comment: Многие из таких приложений сделаны на Elecrtron и вроде как тестировать их можно через ChromeDriver для этого в ChromeOptions для свойства option.BinaryLocation =
      "C:\\mydev\\electron-quick-start-master\\node_modules\\electron\\dist\\electron.exe"; путь до вашего приложения

Comment: @b-vandyshev, спасибо попробую

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант использовать proxy, перехватывать и разбирать сетевой трафик и выцеплять номер телефона из запроса тут можно воспользоваться проектом [Titanium](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy)