# Доступ к элементам формы из другого процесса в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется дескриптор формы стороннего процесса. Мне нужно получить содержимое текстового поля из этой формы. Возможно ли это сделать, имея её дескриптор?

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509662/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820098/184217)

Comment: См. [SendMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) и [WM_GETTEXT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-gettext)